# Detaching console window after UseShellExecute

Tags: c#, process, console-application, processstartinfo

I am running a console application process attached to my C# application using UseShellExecute and CreateNoWindow options and redirecting the input and output to my application.

Now if the user tries to close my C# application while the console process is still running, I want to detach from the console application by recreating the console window (which was never created at launch) and let the user run/interact with the console application independently.

Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not possible.